# How can I override Authenticate.php to take me to an external website?

Tags: php, laravel, inertiajs

I'm using Laravel, the Authenticate.php class currently only returns a route which means the handling of the redirect is happening elsewhere which I cannot find. I want to change the redirect handler so that it uses Inertia::location to redirect to a subdomain if not logged in rather than a route on my current application as inertia doesn't allow routing to subdomains because of CORS. Unless there's a way to bypass that which I am open to also.